# I am looking for way to use a value from sub query

Tags: sql

As the title shows
I am looking for a way to use a value from subquery without using "JOIN".

Please　, someone, tell me that it is impossible or not?

```
SELECT A.column1  A.colomn2  B.column.1/*I want to use it*/  
from A   
where  A.column1  in (select cokumn1 column3 from B )
```

Actual SQL

```
select 
    no,
    sum(case when type = 'A' then cost else -cost end) * 0.25 as cal 
from tr 
where 
    tr.type in ('A', 'B') 
    and exists (select 1 from users u where u.no = c.no)
group by no
```

```
TR_TABLE
NO,COST,TYPE
1,1000,A
1,500, B
1,200, A
2,100, A
```

```
Users
id.No,age
```

Ideal

```
No, Cost , cal , age 
No1  COST  700,m
No2  COST  100,f
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a correlated subquery.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT A.column1, A.column2,
       (SELECT B.column1
        FROM B
        WHERE B.column3 = A.column3
       )
from A;
```

Comment: Thenk you for answering it. but it seems like not good.       %s Invalid identifier error happened

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood it and It should work as suggested in the answer,

I used your query with minor name change and with your expected result ,

```
select no,
       sum(case 
           when c_type = 'A' then 
               cost
           else 
              -cost
           end) cal,
       (select u.gender
           from users u 
         where u.no = tr.no) gender
from tr_table tr
where tr.c_type in ('A', 'B')
group by no
```

order by no;

*dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4f953d0765e307314aa8eb39167fc5f)*

Answer (score 0):

Good day,user2006734. If in result need age  try this please :

```
select A.no,'COST',B.age,
sum(case when A.type = 'A' then A.cost else -A.cost end) * 0.25 as cal

 from
(select no,cost,type from tr where  tr.type in ('A', 'B') ) as A,
(select no,age from users) as B
 where A.no=B.no

group by A.no,'COST',B.age
```